# Bidirectional socket in List

Tags: sockets, lisp, usocket

I'm trying to communicate from a Lisp script to another program by using TCP/IP sockets (with sbcl and the usocket library in a Linux system).

So far I got this code:

```
(require 'asdf)
(require 'usocket)

(defun start-client ()
    (   usocket:with-client-socket
    (socket stream "0.0.0.0" 30000)


    (loop for x in '("1~%" "2~%" "3~%" "4~%" "5~%") do 
        (format stream x)
        (force-output stream)
        (sleep 1)
        ;;(format t "~A~%" (read-line stream))
    )
    )
)
(start-client)
```

The code works well with the exception of the commented line:

```
(format t "~A~%" (read-line stream))
```

So I'm able to send and receive the messages 1,2,3 ... from the other socket (another program) and send messages back from the other program to lisp. However, when I uncomment the line to read the messages from lisp, the above code seems to stop and wait forever.

Comment: Probably a good time, while you are waiting for answers, to think about formatting your code in a readable way. There is room for improvement. Let us know if you need help - well formatted and indented code makes it easier for your audience to read your code.

Comment: Also a great thing for a question would be a real test case to reproduce. As it is now we can only guess what you do and what the server does. Until you provide such a test case we can reproduce I, sadly, have to vote to close this question, because there is not enough information.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to tell what your problem is, without knowing the server.  Maybe it never terminates the line?

Here is a little demo, using threads to isolate client and server:

```
(in-package #:cl-user)

(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (ql:quickload '("usocket" "bordeaux-threads")))

(defpackage #:usocket-demo
  (:use #:cl))

(in-package #:usocket-demo)

(defun serve (port)
  "Starts a socket server to answer a single request."
  (usocket:with-socket-listener (server-socket "0.0.0.0" port
                                               :reuse-address t)
    (let* ((stream-socket (usocket:socket-accept server-socket))
           (server-stream (usocket:socket-stream stream-socket))
           (request (read-line server-stream)))           ; read
      (format t "S> serving…~%")
      (format server-stream "Hello, ~a!~%" request)       ; write
      (finish-output server-stream))))

(defun cly (port)
  "Makes a single request to a server and prints the answer."
  (usocket:with-client-socket (client-socket client-stream "0.0.0.0" port)
    (format client-stream "Issa me!~%")                   ; write
    (finish-output client-stream)
    (let ((response (read-line client-stream)))           ; read
      (format t "C> I got a response: ~a~%" response))))

(defun run-demo ()
  (let ((bt:*default-special-bindings*
          `((*standard-output* . ,*standard-output*))))
    (bt:make-thread (lambda ()
                      (serve 13575))
                    :name "Server")
    (bt:make-thread (lambda ()
                      (cly 13575))
                    :name "Client")
    (values)))
```

The binding of `bt:*default-special-bindings` is necessary so that the threads see the same output stream for the demo messages.

As you see, both client and server have a stream that they can read from and write to.